# Making high voltage DC-DC boost converter circuit

Tags: mosfet, diodes, dc-dc-converter

I’m trying to make very fast charger for my capacitor, to do so I am making my own circuit however .

I saw [this video on Youtube](https://youtu.be/ug82NsxXL94).

And thought of making this circuit, fortunately he shared the schematic.

[image]

I have all components of this circuit but can not found the same ultrafast diode 15 A 1000 V and mosfet 47n60 (47A - 600 V) he is using in his video.

I have a higher rating:

Mosfet (SPW47N60C3) (47 A - 650 V) instead of 47n60 (47A - 600 V)
SPW47N60C3 datasheet

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/80111/INFINEON/SPW47N60C3.html

Diode HFA30PB120 (ultrafast 30 A -1200 V) instead of his ultrafast diode (15 A 1000 V)
HFA30PB120 datasheet

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/143496/IRF/HFA30PB120.html

Can I replace them without affecting the circuit function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a terrible circuit, but it won't be made terribler by substituting a diode of comparable (within 2x) rating.

Mind, I make no guarantees of it working, as-is *or* substituted.

Comment: could you explain why it is that bad?! , i see it is very basic boost converter, the only thing i was doubt about is the 10 kohm resistor won't be enough to discharge the gate of mosfet as well the internal structure won't  allow this perfectly, but i think i will try to use 10k ohm, if it is not ok i will use pull down on the gate but after watching the video i realized it could work

Comment: You asked about substitution; perhaps you should ask a new question about explaining the circuit?

Comment: ok, i will do this